# Regex to match exact words and convert match into tags

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I want to match exact words but with the regex it match's words like

- live with live-streaming
- US with US-led

`keywords = "US",live","xxxx"...`

```js
var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]);
```

using `\s` option add space to the matched string

I am actually matching string and converting then to tags by prepending `#` to each matched words but above pattern match with the words as mentioned

```
$(keywords).each(function() {
    var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]); //looks for match outside html tags
    //var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\s)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]); //looks for match outside html tags
    var rs = "<a class='keyword' href='#'><span class='tag-keyword'>$1</span></a>";
    el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
});

$(".tag-keyword").prepend("#");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? `live-streaming`? or the whole phrase?

Comment: let us say my keywords are `keywords = "US",live","xxxx"...`

Comment: The first string from the strings with a hiphen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce the word boundary at the hyphen with the help of a look-ahead that will check if there is an obligatory space or end of string:

```
(?=\s|$)
```

Like

```
\blive\b(?=\s|$)(?![^<]*?>)
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pF0tO5/1).

Remember that in JavaScript, when you use a RegExp constructor notation, [you must use double slash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules
>   (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are
>   necessary.

```
 var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?=\\s|$)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]);
```

Comment: for me it doesnt work at all & goesnt match with any words `var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?=\s|$)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]);`

Comment: It should be `var pattern = new RegExp("(\\b"+this+"\\b)(?=\\s|$)(?![^<]*?>)", ["gi"]);`